# Spring boot email pdf attachment receiving as blank

Tags: java, spring-boot, base64, byte, encoder

In my spring boot application I need to send pdf file as attachment. I am using below code

```
 InputStream resource = new ClassPathResource("MyPdfFile").getInputStream();
                    byte [] encodedByte = Base64.getEncoder().encode(resource.readAllBytes());
                    if (encodedByte != null) {
                        String encodedString = new String(encodedByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        myPdf.setValue(encodedString);
                        myPdf.setName("MyPdfFile");
                    }
                     attachmentsList.add(myPdf);
```

While receiving email, I am receiving the pdf as all pages as blank page.
Am I missing anything in this code. I spent lot of time on this analysis
Can any one please help me on this

Comment: Why isn’t `attachmentsList.add(myPdf);` put within the `if` block? I guess `mypdf` object is null here.

Comment: I am still getting attachment as blank page